# Bulgarian-Turkish border crossing from Sofia to Istanbul

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, turkey

I'm from Cameroon and I have a valid Bulgarian visa. Is it possible for me to cross to Turkey to visit and do some shopping? And if yes, do I need a visa from a consulate to enter Turkey or will I be issued a visa at the border, and how much does this cost?

Answer (score 2):

From [Visa Information For Foreigners](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa):

> Cameroon: [...removed info for diplomatic passport holders...]
>   Ordinary passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey.
>   Ordinary passport holders with a valid Schengen or OECD member's visa or residence permit may get their one month period single entry e-Visas via the website www.evisa.gov.tr.

Since Bulgaria is part of neither the Schengen area nor the OECD, you will be required to apply for a visa (presumably from the Turkish consulate). I could not find information on how much this visa costs.

Comment: Bulgaria is neither a Schengen nor an OECD member. Why do you think he's eligible for an electronic visa?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Thanks, my mistake. I had misread the status of the Bulgarian membership in the Schengen area. It appears that Bulgaria intends to join both Schengen and OECD in the near future though (but that doesn't help matters today).

Answer (score 1):

From [Visa Information For Foreigners](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa):

> Cameroon: [...removed info for diplomatic passport holders...]
>   Ordinary passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey.
>   Ordinary passport holders with a valid Schengen or OECD member's visa or residence permit may get their one month period single entry e-Visas via the website www.evisa.gov.tr.

If you only have a Bulgarian visa (Bulgaria is neither a Schengen nor an OECD member), this means that you have to apply for a visa at a Turkish consulate or embassy. You are *not* entitled to enter Turkey without a visa and not able to get a visa at the border.